# La geolocalización de Google no funciona en la webview de Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Tengo un comercio electrónico que utilizará la webview con Kotlin en Android:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        title = "Delivery"
        val window: Window = this@MainActivity.window
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this@MainActivity, R.color.black)

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val webView = binding.webView
        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webView.loadUrl("https://delivery.site.com.br/")
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        webView.settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true)
        webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        val webView = binding.webView
        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack()
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```

**Permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

En el proyecto usaremos la ubicación del usuario. Estamos usando el siguiente código:

```
<form method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="BtnLocalizacao" value="Minha Localização">
    </form>
    <?php if($_POST["BtnLocalizacao"] == "Minha Localização"){ ?>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=CHAVE&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>
    <div id="map" style="width: 350px; height: 350px;"></div>
   <!-- <label>Latitude: <span id="lat"></span></label><br>
    <label>Longitude: <span id="lon"></span></label> -->
    <script>
      var lat;
      var lon;
      function getLocation(){
        if(!navigator.geolocation)
           return null;
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos)=>{
           lat =  pos.coords.latitude;
           lon =  pos.coords.longitude;
           const LAT = pos.coords.latitude;
           const LNG = pos.coords.longitude;
           const KEY = "CHAVE";    
           let url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${LAT},${LNG}&key=${KEY}`;
           fetch(url)
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                let parts = data.results[0].address_components;
                document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
                  "beforeend",
                  `<p>Endereço: ${data.results[0].formatted_address}</p>`
                );
                parts.forEach(part => {
                  if (part.types.includes("country")) {
                    //we found "country" inside the data.results[0].address_components[x].types array
                    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
                      "beforeend",
                      `<p>País: ${part.long_name}</p>`
                    );
                  }
                  if (part.types.includes("administrative_area_level_1")) {
                    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
                      "beforeend",
                      `<p>Estado: ${part.long_name}</p>`
                    );
                  }
                  if (part.types.includes("administrative_area_level_3")) {
                    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
                      "beforeend",
                      `<p>LEVEL 3: ${part.long_name}</p>`
                    );
                  }
                });
              })
              .catch(err => console.warn(err.message));
                initMap();
           });
      }
      function initMap(){
        const uluru = {lat: lat, lng: lon};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),{
            center: uluru,
            zoom: 15,
        });
        const marker = new  google.maps.Marker({
           position: uluru,
           map: map,
        });
      }
      getLocation();    
      
    </script>
    <?php } ?>
```

Como resultado, muestra el mapa de texto y la dirección del usuario. El problema es que dentro de la aplicación webview no funciona, solo directamente a través del navegador. Creo que es un problema con la orientación en Javascript o permisso, pero ahora estoy aprendiendo a trabajar con Kotlin.

Es como si no pudiera leer las líneas:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=CHAVE&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>

let url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${LAT},${LNG}&key=${KEY}`;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aqui]

Comment: No carga porque en tu código tratas de cagar otra url : webView.loadUrl("https://delivery.site.com.br/")

Answer (score 0):

Al ver el mapa de color gris, la primera causa es que no tienes una API Key correcta o que la API no se encuentra habilitada, primeramente debes habilitar [Google
Maps JavaScript API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/maps-backend.googleapis.com), después [configura tu proyecto para obtener la API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/cloud-setup)

Asegura primeramente que tu mapa se puede desplegar correctamente en tu página web:

[image: Jorgesys Google Maps JavaScript API]

En tu aplicación el único permiso que necesitas es

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Solo necesitas cargar la url de tu página que contiene el mapa:

```
    val url = "https://googledroids.com/html/mymap.html"
    val webView = binding.mapWebview
    webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    webView.loadUrl(url)
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
    webView.settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true)
    webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]